# Resources to learn about increasing test code coverage

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, testing

Are there any good resources (books, websites) to learn how to increase test code coverage? Especially geared towards C# and Silverlight development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of books on Amazon - try searching for test driven development.